# Saving a json file to the Document directory in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, file, android-studio, fileoutputstream

I am currently trying to create a json file and then save it in the Document directory in Android Studio (version 3.3)

My issue is that everytime I try to create a FileOutputStream I get the error message:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/LoanCalculationResults.json (Permission denied)
```

How I create my FileOutputStream:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "LoanCalculationResults.json"));
```

I have tried using `openFileOutput`, but since it won't accept path separators I can't save the file to the Documents Directory.

I have included **permission** in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

There is something I am missing, and would be very happy if anyone is able to point me in the right direction or link to a resource which can help me!

Comment: this might help you..https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

Comment: Have looked through this many times, but even with this resource I am not able to find a way save my .json file to Documents Directory. I just get that error I have linked in the question everytime I use the example they show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter
                    (openFileOutput("Your file name"+ ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

            outputStreamWriter.write("What you want to write inside the file");
            outputStreamWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: This ignore the core of my question, I want to save the file to the Document Directory specifically. I know one can use **openFileOutput** to save a file, but then you can not specify where! It will always end up in **files/<name_of_file>**